# What is the difference between BOOL and bool?

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, mfc

In VC++ we have the data type “BOOL” which can assume the value TRUE or FALSE, and we have the data type “bool”, which can assume the value true or false.

What is the difference between them and when should each data type be used?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

`bool` is a built-in C++ type while `BOOL` is a Microsoft specific type that is defined as an `int`. You can find it in `windef.h`:

```
typedef int                 BOOL;

#ifndef FALSE
#define FALSE               0
#endif

#ifndef TRUE
#define TRUE                1
#endif
```

The values for a `bool` are `true` and `false`, whereas for `BOOL` you can use any `int` value, though `TRUE` and `FALSE` macros are defined in the `windef.h` header.

This means that the `sizeof` operator will yield 1 for `bool` (the standard states, though, that the size of `bool` is implementation defined), and 4 for `BOOL`.

Source: [Codeguru article](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=332831)

Comment: sizeof(BOOL) is still 4 on a 64-bit Windows machine.  Isolating itself from the compiler type implementations is the reason these typedefs exist.

Comment: @Hans Removed the 64-bit reference.

Comment: WARNING: sizeof(bool) is not specified in microsoft c++ and changed from 4 bytes to 1 byte between c++ 4.2 and 5.0 (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en-use/library/tf4dy80a.aspx)

Answer (score 16):

Windows API had this type before `bool` was thrown into C++. And that's why it still exits in all Windows function that take BOOL. C doesn't support `bool` data-type, therefore `BOOL` has to stay.

Comment: The C99 standard does include a bool type, though it's definitely true that most C compilers did not support bool until relatively recently.

Comment: If you want the C++ like bools in Standard C, #include <stdbool.h>

Answer (score 15):

To add to what luvieere has said, you can return something other than `TRUE` or `FALSE` from a function returning a `BOOL` e.g.,

```
BOOL myFunc(int a)
{
    if (a < 3) return FALSE;
    else if (a > 3) return TRUE;
    else return 2;
}
```

And this is possible because a `BOOL` is essentially an `int`.

Please note that this is not advisable as it severely destroys the general readability of code but it is something you can come across and you will be wondering why it is so.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that this is a really bad idea. The whole reason to use BOOL is to restrict the values to TRUE/FALSE; if you want `int` you should use `int`.

Comment: Many (but not all) Windows API functions treat any non-zero `BOOL` as `TRUE`. Because this behaviour is not consistent, you should always explicitly use `TRUE` (i.e. `1`) and not non-zero. This can be tricky because [some languages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14462348/1836776) define `True` as all bits set (`-1` for signed integers)