# Why is True equal to -1

Tags: vb.net

I was wondering why True is equal to -1 and not 1. If I remember correctly (back in the days) in C, "true" would be equal to 1.

```
    Dim t, f As Integer

    t = True
    f = False

    Console.WriteLine(t) ' -1
    Console.WriteLine(f) ' 0
    Console.ReadLine()
```

Comment: True has all bits set to 1. Which happens to equal -1 for all signed integer types.

Comment: In C, false is equal to 0. Any other value is true, including -1. Notice that -1 equals `not 0` using a binary `not`

Comment: You should really consider to set [`OPTION STRICT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs(v=vs.110).aspx) to `true`. There's no reason why you need an implict conversion from `Int32` to `Boolean` or any other magic conversion that opens the door for nasty errors. `Strict` also has the advantage that you start to learn the .NET types and that you're C# compliant.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Casting a boolean to an integer returns -1 for true?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621037/casting-a-boolean-to-an-integer-returns-1-for-true)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

When you cast any non-zero number to a `Boolean`, it will evaluate to `True`.  For instance:

```
Dim value As Boolean = CBool(-1) ' True
Dim value1 As Boolean = CBool(1) ' True
Dim value2 As Boolean = CBool(0) ' False
```

However, as you point out, any time you cast a `Boolean` that is set to `True` to an `Integer`, it will evaluate to -1, for instance:

```
Dim value As Integer = CInt(CBool(1)) ' -1
```

The reason for this is because `-1` is the signed-integer value where all of its bits are equal to 1.  Since a `Boolean` is stored as a 16-bit integer, it is easier to toggle between true and false states by simply NOT'ing all of the bits rather than only NOT'ing the least significant of the bits.  In other words, in order for `True` to be `1`, it would have to be stored like this:

```
True  = 0000000000000001
False = 0000000000000000
```

But it's easier to just store it like this:

```
True  = 1111111111111111
False = 0000000000000000
```

The reason it's easier is because, at the low-level:

```
1111111111111111 = NOT(0000000000000000)
```

Whereas:

```
0000000000000001 <> NOT(0000000000000000)
0000000000000001 = NOT(1111111111111110)
```

For instance, you can replicate this behavior using `Int16` variables like this:

```
Dim value As Int16 = 0
Dim value2 As Int16 = Not value
Console.WriteLine(value2) ' -1
```

This would be more obvious if you were using unsigned integers, because then, the value of `True` is the maximum value rather than -1.  For instance:

```
Dim value As UInt16 = CType(True, UInt16) ' 65535
```

So, the real question, then, is why in the world does VB.NET use 16 bits to store a single bit value.  The real reason is speed.  Yes, it uses 16 times the amount of memory, but a processor can do 16-bit boolean operations a lot faster than it can do single-bit boolean operations.

Side note: The reason why the `Int16` value of `-1` is stored as `1111111111111111` instead of as `1000000000000001`, as you might expect (where the first bit would be the "sign bit", and the rest would be the value), is because it is stored as the two's-complement.  Storing negative numbers as the two's-complement means that arithmetic operations are much easier for the processor to perform.  It's also safer because, with two's-compliment, there's no way to represent `0` as a negative number, which could cause all sorts of confusion and bugs.

Comment: Great answer!  I never considered that `NOT(1) <> 0` would be an issue.

Answer (score 2):

Is most language, a numeric value of 0 is false. Everything else is considered true. If I remeber correctly, -1 is actually all bits set to 1 while 0 is all bits set to 0. I guess this is why.

Comment: Yep, you'll see the words "non-zero" a lot for "true"

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Basic, `0` is `False` whereas any non-zero value is `True`. Also, per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wts33hb3.aspx):

> When Visual Basic converts numeric data type values to Boolean, 0
>   becomes False and all other values become True. When Visual Basic
>   converts Boolean values to numeric types, False becomes 0 and True
>   becomes -1.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the possible duplicate: [Casting a boolean to an integer returns -1 for true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621037/casting-a-boolean-to-an-integer-returns-1-for-true)

> Boolean constant True has numeric value −1. This is because the Boolean data type is stored as a 16-bit signed integer. In this construct −1 evaluates to 16 binary 1s (the Boolean value True), and 0 as 16 0s (the Boolean value False). This is apparent when performing a Not operation on a 16 bit signed integer value 0 which will return the integer value −1, in other words True = Not False. This inherent functionality becomes especially useful when performing logical operations on the individual bits of an integer such as And, Or, Xor and Not.[4] This definition of True is also consistent with BASIC since the early 1970s Microsoft BASIC implementation and is also related to the characteristics of CPU instructions at the time.

Answer (score 0):

I guess to goes back to assembly language where a conditional is translated to a compare `cmp` operation and the zero flag (`ZF`) is checked. For true expressions the `ZF` is not raised, and for false expressions it is. Early Intel processors are like that, but I cannot remember if the Zilog `Z80` and the Motorola 8-bit processors had the same convention.