# NullReferenceException when using Group.FirstOrDefault with Value Type

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, linq-expressions

This is the extract of a linq expression:

```
Dim charges As List(Of IndividualCharge) = (From t In totals
                    Group t By t.InvId
                    Into Group
                    Select New IndividualCharge With {
                    .VatRate = Group.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.VatRate).VatRate
                    }).ToList()
```

It appears that when `x.VatRate` is `0`, `FirstOrDefault` throws an exception:

[image: NullReferenceException]

I can confirm this by swapping it out for:

`.VatRate = Group.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) 0).VatRate`

which ensures an exception every time.

- Why is a null reference exception thrown (this is a value type, hence no references)?
- How do I deal with the situation where x.VatRate is actually `0`?

Comment: @Skippy - The meaning isn't relevant

Comment: I'm not doing any division as you seem to think

Comment: In this scenario it is just a number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're misreading the error, compounded by VB.NET's type coercion.

> Group.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.VatRate).VatRate

[FirstOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549039.aspx) returns the first value matching the predicate function, or the default value of `T` if nothing matches. Since your function doesn't evaluate to `true` or `false`, VB.NET coerces the `int` to a `bool`. In that scenario, [`0` is converted to `false` and any other value is converted to `true`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14462348/2199).

So, when `x.VatRate` is not `0`, then the first `IndividualCharge` passes the predicate filter. When `VatRate` is `0`, then no `IndividualCharge` passes the predicate filter and `null` (the default value of `IndividualCharge`) is returned. Trying to grab the `VatRate` then results in your `NullReferenceException`.

Presumably, you really wanted the first `VatRate`, whether it was 0 or not. Changing your code to:

```
Group.Select(Function(x) x.VatRate).First()
```

should accomplish that.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass a expression to FirstOrDefault your telling it select the first item that matches the expression (much like a Where clause but for the first object to match the clause).  If you changed your statement to the following is it ok?

```
Dim charges As List(Of IndividualCharge) = (From t In totals
                    Group t By t.InvId
                    Into Group
                    Select New IndividualCharge With {
                    .VatRate = Group.FirstOrDefault().VatRate
                    }).ToList()
```

If you wanted to get the first value that isn't zero something along these lines should do?

```
Dim charges As List(Of IndividualCharge) = (From t In totals
                    Group t By t.InvId
                    Into Group
                    Select New IndividualCharge With {
                    .VatRate = if(Group.Any(function(o) o.VatRate > 0),  Group.FirstOrDefault(function(o) o.VatRate > 0).VatRate, -1)
                    }).ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by VBs implicit type coercion. The `FirstOrDefault` method expects a function which returns a `Boolean`. You are passing a function which returns a `Decimal`, so VB converts it to:

```
Group.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.VatRate <> 0)
```

If none of the items in the group have a non-zero `VatRate`, this will return `Nothing`. You then try to access the `VatRate` property on the returned object, which results in a `NullReferenceException`.

Try using:

```
Group.Where(Function(x) x.VatRate <> 0)
   .Select(Function(x) x.VatRate)
   .FirstOrDefault()
```

That should return the first non-zero `VatRate` if there is one, or zero otherwise.