# Application.FileDialog.Show = -1?

Tags: vba, excel

This is less of a problem question, and more of an understanding question.

I stole the code below:

```
Dim fd as Office.FileDialog

FileDialog.
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        With fd
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Title = "Please select the file to process."
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Text files", "*.txt"
        .InitialFileName = "C:\"
    End With
If fd.Show = -1 Then
sFilename = fd.SelectedItems(1)
Else
    MsgBox ("You did not pick a file! Cancelling macro.")
    Exit Sub
End If
```

I do not recall where I got the code from, but it was a while ago. I found this in an old macro and upon looking at it, I do not understand the `If` statement.

```
If fd.Show = -1 Then
```

I thought `Application.FileDialog.Show` was a `boolean` expression, and I understand that 0 typically means False, and 1 typically means True. What in the world does -1 mean?

The code works perfectly, and I've tried to research the topic, but everything I find says either "True" or "False". Any insight is much appreciated.

Comment: In VB Land int(true) is -1 not 1 / See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14462272/why-is-true-equal-to-1

Comment: For the reason *why* true is -1, [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/3418/data-types-and-limits/11778/boolean#t=201612081644123119612).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would be more readable, and completely equivalent:

```
If fd.Show Then
    sFilename = fd.SelectedItems(1)
Else
    MsgBox "You did not pick a file! Cancelling macro."
    Exit Sub
End If
```

I've removed the extraneous parentheses around the `MsgBox` arguments, since `MsgBox` is being called as a procedure here and not a function, and thus all the parentheses do is force VBA to evaluate the string as a value, ...which it already is. Using extraneous parentheses as a habit can lead to stupid and unexpected bugs and compilation errors.

As already mentioned in comments, the `-1` literal really just stands for `True` in this case.

Same as this:

```
If fd.Show = True Then
```

But then, that would be redundant, since a Boolean value is already a *Boolean expression*, so there's never a need to compare a Boolean value to *make* a Boolean expression and satisfy the `If` syntax:

```
If {bool-expression} Then
    {statements}
End If
```

> *I understand that 0 typically means False, and 1 typically means True*

Not quite. `0` means `False`, yes, but `True` is just nothing more than *not false*: any non-zero integer value will convert to `True`:

```
Debug.Print CBool(42) 'prints True
Debug.Print CBool(-12) 'prints True
Debug.Print CBool(0) 'prints False
```

Comment: +1 Wow. Very nice explanation. I will have to try out the whole `Not False` idea. I've never actually tried to put anything in a boolean expression other than True and False. Thank you for the info!

Comment: If you'd rather avoid implicit conversion, you can do `If CBool(fs.Show) Then` for ultimate readability =)

Comment: Ah yes, because doing an `If` followed by a boolean is basically just stating `If bool = True`? Or do I have to explicitly use `CBool()` in order to use that?

Comment: @SalvadorVayshun This video explains why False is 0 and True is <> 0: [Excel Magic Trick 652: Boolean Logic for Logical & Array Formulas](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6XX7UBmP3rM)

Comment: @SalvadorVayshun Exactly - that's specifically what I meant with *that would be redundant, since a Boolean value is already a Boolean expression*. If you don't make the explicit conversion, VBA will make an implicit one.

Answer (score 2):

Actually this Is an Office control and "Show" returns a long.  -1 Means the User pressed the Accept Button and 0 Means they pressed the Cancel button.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865217.aspx

Comment: Good eye! That's where I stole the code from! Thanks for pointing this out.