# Why does this VBA code give -25 and not 25?

Tags: vba

This is a snippet from a book I am reading:

```
Sub VariantDemo()
  MyVar = True
  MyVar = MyVar * 100
  MyVar = MyVar / 4
  MyVar = "Answer: " & MyVar
  MsgBox MyVar
End Sub
```

In the answer box it says "Answer: -25"?, but why do we have the minus? When I calculate the value directly in Excel, the value is 25.

Comment: Because `True` = `-1`

Comment: Not sure what the background context is but you are using `MyVar` to store Boolean, Integer, and String type values. I would avoid that if this is being used in some other context

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/data-types/boolean-data-type#type-conversions

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14462272/why-is-true-equal-to-1

Comment: Thanks, it is weird that Excel and VBA treats TRUE different.

Comment: Are you missing `Dim MyVar as Variant` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is True equal to -1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14462272/why-is-true-equal-to-1)

Comment: @arnis, is this not the entire point of the demo function, given that the Sub is called VariantDemo? It's explaining the perils of not typing variables appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

In VBA is most other languages the numerical value of `False` is `0` and any other value is `True`. As a matter of convention and convenience, the value of `True` is cast as a signed integer as `-1` and thus in your example `-1*100/4 = -25`.

For all signed integers a value filled with `1` bits, such as `11111111` equals `-1`. This is because of [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) which maximizes storage for types where the first bit is the sign bit.