# how to read bool from unmanaged memory, using Marshal class?

Tags: c#, interop, marshalling

[Marshal class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.aspx) doesn't contain `ReadBool` method. If my c++ structure contains `bool` field then how should I read it? I've tried to do this: `(bool) Marshal.ReadInt32(intPointer, offset)` but it is not allowed to cast int32 to bool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sizeof(bool)` in C++ [is implementation-defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897844/is-sizeofbool-defined), so it might be better to define the field in the struct as an integer of a known size (e.g., `int32_t` or [`BOOL`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6420526/difference-bool-and-bool)). Then it's customary use `0` to indicate `false` and not-`0` to indicate `true`:

```cpp
// C++
intPointer->int32_t_field = bool_value ? 1 : 0;
```

```cs
// C#
bool result = Marshal.ReadInt32(intPointer, offset) != 0;
```