# 'TRUE' was not declared in this scope C++

Tags: c++

So I have this simple function and it is suppose to return true or false. True is only returned 2% of the time and false every other time. However, whenever I try to compile the full code I get the error message;

> 'TRUE' was not declared in this scope C++

I am aware I can use `int` instead of `bool` and just use `1` for true and `0` for false, but I want to figure out why this won't work. Any help?

Here is my function:

```
bool Bunny::determineMutant()
{
    int rand_num = rand() % 100 + 1; //random num 1-100
    if(rand_num == 1 || rand_num == 2) return TRUE;
    else return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Try not using capitals

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`TRUE` and `FALSE` are often [associated with the Win32 type `BOOL`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6420526/3747990), alternatively a macro for the integers `1` and `0`. The actual error is there since the definition of `TRUE` is not available.

For the [built in C++ type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types) `bool` use `true` and `false`. I think this should be the preferred solution here.

*As a side note*, the code could be simplified to return based on the condition in the `if()` which is already a `bool`;

```
return (rand_num == 1 || rand_num == 2);
```

Answer (score 4):

The keywords in C++ are lowercase `true` and `false`.

The all-caps `TRUE` and `FALSE` are generally preprocessor macros of `1` and `0` respectively in VC++, and are used to return the [type `BOOL`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6420526/difference-bool-and-bool).

Comment: I believe Cocoa defines them too.