# Marshal.Sizeof and BitConverter.GetBytes behave differently on booleans

Tags: c#, boolean, sizeof, bitconverter

Let's consider this piece of code :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(bool)));
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", BitConverter.GetBytes(true)));
}
```

if bool is 1 byte, I'd expect it to output

> 1
>   1

and if bool is 4 bytes (as an int), I'd expect

> 4
>   1, 0, 0, 0 // let's forget about the endianness

However, it outputs (in x64)

> 4
>   1

That's quite an issue for me in marshaling code. Who should I trust?

Please note that GetBytes takes a boolean as input : 
[image]

Comment: which is then 4 bytes. Then why bitconverter returns only 1 byte?

Comment: And GetBytes convert the bool value to a byte array, so one byte here.

Comment: @Regis [`BitConverter.GetBytes(true)`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/bitconverter.cs,41) specifically returns either `(byte)1` or `(byte)0`

Comment: @canton7 : nope. Look at the update. It takes a bool.

Comment: @Regis "nope" what, exactly?

Comment: there is an overload for boolean. Or the cast happens inside the implementation

Comment: @Regis Are you referring to `BitConverter.GetBytes` or `Marshal.SizeOf`? `BitConverter.GetBytes` has an overload which takes a bool yes, but that method (which I linked the implementation of) specifically returns a `byte`.

Comment: Why is this downvoted?

Comment: @canton7 You're right - I misread the code! The actual answer is that bytes are *marshalled* as 32-bit values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both of your ways of measuring the size of a `bool` are flawed.

`Marshal.SizeOf` is used to determine how much memory is taken when the given type is marshalled to unmanaged code. A `bool` is marshalled to a windows `BOOL` type, which is 4 bytes.

`BitConverter.GetBytes(bool)` is effectively implemented like this:

```
public static byte[] GetBytes(bool value) {
    byte[] r = new byte[1];
    r[0] = (value ? (byte)1 : (byte)0 );
    return r;
}
```

[Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/bitconverter.cs,41).

Therefore it always returns a single-element array.

What you're probably after is `sizeof(byte)`, which "returns the number of bytes occupied by a variable of a given type" ([MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/sizeof)). `sizeof(bool)` returns `1`.

Comment: Well thanks. Then why the implementation of GetBytes doesn’t match the actual size of the book (when marshaled to unmanaged memory)

Comment: One thing that this doesn't explain is why `Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(char))` returns 1, which leads me to wonder how 2-byte UTF16 chars can be marshalled in a single byte without potential data loss...

Comment: @Matthew Compatibility with Win9x and ANSI, [apparently](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/39641#issuecomment-513441958). The actual runtime marshalling code is a lot smarter than this: it knows to call the right xxxA/xxxW overload, and marshal strings accordingly, etc.

Comment: @Regis `BitConverter` has nothing to do with marshalling types to unmanaged code - they're entirely separate. `BitConverter` does its own thing. It can re-interpret things it's written, given that you're running on a machine with the same endianness, but it relies on various details (like endianness, that floating-point is implemented in a particular way, etc)

Answer (score 0):

The case here is that Marshal.SizeOf returns the size of an **unmanaged** type in bytes and unmanaged equivalent of boolean is a 4-byte Win32 BOOL type. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/6420546/3478025 for details